# Play Framework 2.5 IO error while decoding ... with UTF-8

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I've been struggling with this for a while now.

I get

```
[error] Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
[error] IO error while decoding C:\Users\xxxx\IdeaProjects\play-scala-seed\target\scala-2.11\routes\main\router\RoutesPrefix.scala with UTF-8
[error] Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application -

! @7469ah5je - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[IO error while decoding C:\Users\xxxx\IdeaProjects\play-scala-seed\target\scala-2.11\routes\main\controllers\ReverseRoutes.scala with UTF-8
Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

when using

```
sbt run
```

to run and trying to hit the index page at localhost:9000 of one of the sample projects downloaded from [Play Framework's website](https://www.playframework.com/).

I've added

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8")
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8")
```

to the `build.sbt` of the project and added the following to my Windows System Environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
PATH : %JAVA_HOME%\bin
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

as suggested by other posts, but still no joy.

```
[error] Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
```

says I should use the -encoding option, but I'm still not sure where I should use it.

Do you guys have any suggestions as to how I should proceed?

Comment: If the encoding has to change. How do I find out to what I should change it to?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to run : 
    sbt run javaOptions in run += "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"

That will tell Java that you want to encode this file in UTF8.

Not sure what your default settings are. But can you please try this?